# establecer caracteres imborrables en input

Tags: html, html5

Como puedo colocar caracteres imborrables en mi input?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por ejemplo en la imagen: necesito que el +52 este siempre sin borrarse, para el usuario solo escriba el numero de teléfono sin la característica de su País.

```
   <input  type="phone" placeholder="Telefono" name="telefono"  minlength="10" maxlength="10" id="telefono">
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como puedo hacer esto?

Comment: Ponlo fuera del input, a su lado, que lo vean, y agrégalo cuando envies el formulario, será lo más cómodo para todos supongo, pues dependerá del script en el servidor.  Si eso lo haces depender de javascript o html te lo podran retocar si quieren y no será 100% seguro nunca.

Comment: O bien usa este truco con html y css: https://www.30secondsofcode.org/css/s/input-with-prefix

Comment: Imagino ha de ser el codigo de area de un pais. Siempre piensa en la escalabilidad. Justo ahora estoy trabajando en un viejo proyecto que fue pensado para solo 1 pais y resulta que ahora se extendio a 6 paises. Y por supuesto el dueño de la empresa no quiere reinvertir en hacerlo nuenuvamee, por lo tanto cada vez que hay que modificar algo trabajamos 6 veces y lo peor son las inconsistencias